# The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the collection: Access is denied

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, powershell

I am trying modify content located in an unattached content DB. But I am having trouble accessing the lists.

Here is my powershell script code:

```
$db=Get-SPContentDatabase -ConnectAsUnattachedDatabase  -DatabaseName wss_content_abc -DatabaseServer SP13DEV $site=$db.Sites[0]

$site.RootWeb.Lists
```

the last line gives me this error message:

> The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the
>   collection: "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))".
>       At line:1 char:1
>       + $site.RootWeb.Lists
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator

I double checked that my account is a DB owner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code below fixed the problem:

```
$webApp = $db.WebApplication
$user = $env:USERDOMAIN+"\"+$env:USERNAME
$webApp.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity($user)
```